# (VBA) How to refresh HTMLDocument object when navigating new html page on same browser?

Tags: vba, excel

I am tasked with creating a macro that logs into a website and navigates to a specific page where a html table can be copied into excel. My problem is that when I try to pull the html table, I get the html table of the previous webpage. My thinking is I need to update my HTMLDocument some how. Is this possible? I unfortunately can't give the specific URL as it's confidential.

My code can be found below.

```
Sub website_login()

'variables
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim Browser As InternetExplorer
Dim HTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim URL As String
Dim l As Object

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
URL = "MY URL"

Set Browser = New InternetExplorer
    Browser.Silent = True
    Browser.navigate URL
    Browser.Visible = True

With Browser
Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
End With

Set HTMLDoc = Browser.document

'fill in login credentials
HTMLDoc.getElementById("username").Value = "USERNAME" 
HTMLDoc.getElementById("password").Value = "PASSWORD"

'loop through collection of INPUT tags and Login In
For Each HTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If HTML_Element.Value = "Login" Then
        HTML_Element.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'will be brought back to login if delays aren't added
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) ' delay 5 seconds
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) ' delay 5 seconds

Browser.navigate ("NEW URL")'navigate to new webpage on same website


'BELOW CODE COPIES TABLE INTO EXCEL
'http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=184695
Dim eleColtr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for tr tags
Dim eleColtd As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for td tags
Dim eleRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Row elements
Dim eleCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Column elements

Set eleColtr = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'Find all tr tags
'This section populates Excel
    i = 0 'start with first value in tr collection
    For Each eleRow In eleColtr 'for each element in the tr collection
        Set eleColtd = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(i).getElementsByTagName("td") 'get all the td elements in that specific tr
        j = 0 'start with the first value in the td collection
        For Each eleCol In eleColtd 'for each element in the td collection
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i, j).Value = eleCol.innerText 'paste the inner text of the td element, and offset at the same time
            j = j + 1 'move to next element in td collection
        Next eleCol 'rinse and repeat
        i = i + 1 'move to next element in td collection
    Next eleRow 'rinse and repeat



Debug.Print "DONE!"
Exit Sub
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: You're setting the DOMdocument _before_ you actually navigate to the desired page...

Comment: Try to wait for readyState on the second "browser.navigate", probably the page is not ready yet.

Comment: So could I just reset HTMLDoc (Set HTMLDoc = Browser.document) after I have navigated my desired page? Or would I have to create a new instance of DOMdocument? thanks for the quick response btw

Comment: @Baro I tried that but it just waits forever.

Comment: I tried setting the DOMdocument after and it worked for the first run, then stopped working :( . I tried creating a new instance of DOMdocument and still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually get my code to work, thanks everyone for their help. @Macro Man was correct in that I didn't set DOMdocument after I navigated to my desired page. So I created a new instance of DOMdocument after my Browser.navigate but that's not all that was needed. For some reason I needed to navigate to my desired page again right before setting my new DOMdocument. I still am confused why this works but who cares it works.

```
Browser.navigate ("URL")


Debug.Print "DELAY STARTED"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) ' delay 5 seconds
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) ' delay 5 seconds
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) ' delay 5 seconds
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) ' delay 5 seconds

Browser.navigate ("URL")'DONT REMOVE OR WILL BREAK
Set WTF = Browser.document ' my new instance of DOMdocument

Debug.Print "Second Delay"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) ' delay 5 seconds
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) ' delay 5 seconds

'*****************************************************************************************************************************************
'http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=184695
Dim eleColtr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for tr tags
Dim eleColtd As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'Element collection for td tags
Dim eleRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Row elements
Dim eleCol As MSHTML.IHTMLElement 'Column elements

Set eleColtr = WTF.getElementsByTagName("tr") 'Find all tr tags
'This section populates Excel
    i = 0 'start with first value in tr collection
    For Each eleRow In eleColtr 'for each element in the tr collection
        Debug.Print "goodnews"
        Set eleColtd = WTF.getElementsByTagName("tr")(i).getElementsByTagName("td") 'get all the td elements in that specific tr
        j = 0 'start with the first value in the td collection
        For Each eleCol In eleColtd 'for each element in the td collection
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Offset(i, j).Value = eleCol.innerText 'paste the inner text of the td element, and offset at the same time
            j = j + 1 'move to next element in td collection
        Next eleCol 'rinse and repeat
        i = i + 1 'move to next element in td collection
    Next eleRow 'rinse and repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not tested:**

Try replacing

```
Set eleColtr = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
```

with this:

```
Set eleColtr = Nothing
For i = 1 To 50
    On Error Resume Next
    Set eleColtr = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    If Err.Number = 91 Then
        GoTo Skip
    End If
    Exit For
Skip:
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:001"))
Next i
```

I have not tested this so if you still get the last table's details, then you need to set HTMLDoc again.